# Shell script to list all Files according to date and send it to HTML file with each line as link

Tags: php, html, c, shell

I want to Write a Shell Script Which Lists all The files and folders recursively according to date

and send it to a html File in which the line containing the file adress acts as a link to that file directory

I came up with this

```
    find . -mtime -100000 -print>latest.html
```

but after that how do i convert each line of the output as a link?

using php or shell script ?

Comment: Do you really need a script? Apache can list directories just fine, if you put _Options +Indexes_ in the config.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed afterwards to convert each line into a link:

```
sed -i.bak 's!.*!<a href="&">&</a>"!' latest.html
```